# Excel 2016 seemingly randomly changes number values I enter

Tags: excel, ms-office

Today I encountered a really weird error in **Excel 2016** **16.0** (on Windows 10.1) that is driving me crazy:

When I enter the number 2.089E-7 into a cell that is formatted as either standard, number, or scientific, excel changes the value to 2.09E-4.
When I click into the cell, the bar on top tells me the value of the cell is 0.0002089, which is exactly the number I entered, except that three decimal orders of magnitude are missing.

I played around a little bit and found out that Excel does this for all numbers that have more than three decimals in the format X.XXXE-7. If I enter, for example, 2.10E-07 the value is correctly stored as 0.00000021.

I have tried everything that came to my mind, including formatting the cell to all available types, closing and re-starting Excel.

What is wrong with my Excel version?

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT for clarification:

Numbers I enter, vs. values that get stored:

2.1E-7 vs. 2.1E-7

2.11E-7 vs. 2.11E-7

2.111E-7 vs. 2.111E-4

2.1111E-7 vs. 2.1111E-3

2.11111E-7 vs. 2.11111E-2

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You are right to try formatting, because this seems like a formatting issue. Select your cell and [try this button in the Ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ulh3.jpg) and see if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not change anything. As I said, every format option I have tried results in the same weird error.